# How do I connect the pickit 3 with PIC32MX795

Tags: pic, pickit

I bought a [USB 32-Bit Whacker - PIC32MX795 Development Board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9713) and a [MPLAB PICkit 3](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9973) after working with some ATmega stuff in the past.

[image]

These are the 6 pins(on the pickit). I'm looking for them on the whacker board.  I can find

- vpp
- 3.3v
- gnd
- pgd
- pgc

in a row, but i'm wondering 2 things

- is vdd the same as 3.3v?
- where / what / do I need the LVP?

Comment: The PIC data sheet and the PICkit 3 documentation will tell you what pins you need to connect. MPLAB should then work with it.

Comment: the pickit has 6 output pins and most connectors on the dev board are 5.. so not sure which ones are correct.

Comment: Just use the first five pins on the PICkit 3.

Comment: You don't need LVP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to look through the datasheet for both the PIC32MX795 and the datasheet for the PicKit 3...These are explained in there. Also looking at schematics for dev kits can make this an easy problem to solve as well.

[image: A quick googling revealed this as well]